# How to get internal tag posts in Ghost

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm currently working on a Ghost blog, but I'm wondering how I might be able to grab all the posts that have a internal tag in Ghost.
I found

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    {{#foreach tags visibility="internal"}}
        {{removeSubstring name '#META:'}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

this code but it only returns tag list not posts.
I want a internal tag posts list, Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't have any connection with ghost-blog I'm afraid. Removing the ghostscript tag.

Answer (score 1):

When you say internal tags do you mean Private Tags? If so then that's not really what private tags are for, you can filter with them though like so:

```
{{#get "posts" filter="tag:hash-tagname"}}
    {{#foreach posts}}
        {{title}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

To get all public tags use the following:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
  {{tags}}
{{/get}}
```

Hope this helps!